# Factor nonsingular symmetrice square matrix $M$ into $A^TA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix $M$ of size $n,n$ consisting of real numbers. It is nonsingular and symmetrice, i.e. $M = M^T$.

Does there exist a factorization whereby $M = A^TA$? I know I can't use Cholesky because the matrix is not necessary positive definite. I would also settle for "approximations" of the decomposition matrix $A$ if my general query isn't answerable.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

No, such a factorization will not exist in general. The reason is that if $A$ is any $ m \times n$ matrix with real entries, then $A^tA$ will always be a positive semidefinite matrix (because $\langle A^tAv,v \rangle = |Av|^2$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$). Thus, if we take any symmetric matrix which is not positive semidefinite, then it cannot be decomposed as $A^tA$.

For a very easy example, take $M$ to be the $1 \times 1$ matrix whose only entry is $-1$. If $A=[a_1 \cdots a_n]$ is any $1 \times n$ matrix such that $A^tA=M$, then we have that $a_1^2+\dots +a_n^2=-1$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you requiring $A$ to be real as well?  If so, the necessary and sufficient condition for such a factorization to exist is that $M$ is positive semidefinite.  If not, there is always such a factorization.